Action on docker log event
I need to perform specific action (run a script or command) on specific log entries of several containers.
I am looking for a way to do this but could not find anything built-in, pre-made or suggestions.
So the task would be to continuously read the logs of multiple containers on a host and if the line contains specific expressions then run the script resp. command on it and perform some tasks on the host. This shall start with the container and stop with the container and run continuously in the background.
